# Parsing json and searching through the output

Tags: python, json

ive this small script read url and print the out , 
how to print only words am looking for , if the keyword = one print the value of it and ignore the rest of json data

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request("http://url/feed.json")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
json = f.read()
print json
```

Comment: I hope you're aware that you just overwrote the entire module `json` by doing `json = json.loads(r.read())` ;)

Comment: yeah :) i just did not post latest modified version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just talking about a `key` being a `keyword` (e.g. `{'key': 'foo_value'}`, then this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request("http://url/feed.json")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
json_response = json.loads(f.read())
keywords = ['key', 'key2', 'key3']
for k, v in json_response.iteritems():
    if k in keywords:
        print(v)
        break
```

### Extra Credit

If you wanted to install the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, you could cut your script down to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

res = requests.get('http://url/feed.json')
json_res = res.json()

keywords = ['key', 'key2', 'key3']
for k, v in json_res.iteritems():
    if k in keywords:
        print(v)
        break
```